# Left clicking, but stimulating right click

Tags: javascript, three.js

This might be strange, but I want to be able to stimulate a right click when the user is left-clicking. If the user left-clicks, I make JavaScript take that left button click, and change it to a right button click. Is this possible?

Comment: no. you can make right turn left, but not left to right.

Comment: Does this question have anything to do with three.js?